# Minimizing $\sqrt{(x+3)^2 + 49} + \sqrt{(x-5)^2 + 64}$

Tags: geometry, optimization, radicals, maxima-minima, geometric-inequalities

> What is the minimum value of
>   $$\sqrt{(x+3)^2 + 49} + \sqrt{(x-5)^2 + 64}$$

I tried getting the first derivative, but I can't solve the equation when I put $y = 0$.

Methods without using calculus are also welcome.

Comment: You are not looking for $y = 0$, but $ \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} = 0 $ . What have you tried?

Comment: How far did you get in simplifying the equation? I guess you at least obtained
$$
\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2 + 49}} + \frac{x-5}{\sqrt{(x-5)^2 + 64}} = 0
$$

Comment: ..... wait I didn't get that. thats why i couldn't get it. thanks!, i forgot the numerator :O

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a solution without words ...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

By Minkowski (triangle inequality) we obtain:
$$\sqrt{(x+3)^2+7^2}+\sqrt{(x-4)^2+8^2}\geq \sqrt{(x+3+4-x)^2+(7+8)^2}=\sqrt{274}$$
The equality occurs for $(x+3,7)||(4-x,8),$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(x)=\frac{x+3}{\sqrt{(x+3)^2+49}}+\frac{x-5}{\sqrt{(x-5)^2+64}}$$
$$f'(x)=0\quad\Rightarrow$$
$$15x^2+874x-649=0$$
$$x=\frac{11}{15},\quad x=-59$$
Then
$$f_{min}=f\left(\frac{11}{15}\right)=17$$

Comment: +1. nice, you have found the same as I found.

Answer (score 0):

Using Triangle Inequality

$$\sqrt{(x+3)^2+7^2}+\sqrt{(x-4)^2+8^2}\geq \sqrt{(3+x+x-7)^2+(7+9)^2}$$

Comment: I think you want $d(\langle x,0\rangle, \langle -3,-7\rangle) + d(\langle x,0\rangle, \langle 4,8\rangle) \ge d(\langle -3,-7\rangle,\langle 4,8\rangle)$ with equality iff $\langle x,0\rangle$ is on the line segment from $\langle -3,-7\rangle$ to $\langle 4,8\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

This function
$$y=\sqrt{(x+3)^2 + 49} + \sqrt{(x-5)^2 + 64}$$
is symmetric about $x=\dfrac{11}{15}$, then since that is sum of two hyperbola, it's shape is like a symmetrical parabola so the minimum accurs in $x=\dfrac{11}{15}$, it is $17$.